# Lower bound on the distance of 1D random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk, probability-limit-theorems

Let $$Z_1, \ldots, Z_n\sim \begin{cases}+1&\text{w.p. 1/2}\\-1& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ be independent Bernoulli variables and let $S_n=Z_1+\ldots+Z_n$ be the result of an unbiased $n$-steps random walk.

Clearly, $\mathbb E(S_n)=0$ and $Var(S_n)=Var(Z_1)+\ldots+Var(Z_n)=n$.

Thus, we can use Chebyshev's inequality and get
$$\Pr\left[S_n\ge k\sqrt n\right] \le k^{-2}.$$

However, I'm interested in a lower bound on the probability that $S_n\ge k\sqrt n$ for a fixed $k=O(1)$. Specifically,

> **Can we find a function $f(k)$ such that for all $n$, $\Pr\left[S_n\ge k\sqrt n\right] \ge f(k)$**?

Comment: For fixed $k$ one can use the central limit theorem: The probability $P(S_n\ge k \sqrt n)$ has a finite non-zero limit as $n\to \infty$. You can use the Berry-Esseen theorem to calculate a particular $c$ for which the inequality holds for all $n$.

Comment: There is no constant $c$ that satisfies your condition for every $k$ and every $n$. Do you need $c$ to depend on $n$ or on $k$ ?

Comment: "assuming Chebyshev's inequality is asymptotically tight here" ... That is rarely the case.

Comment: @tristan - $c$ can depend on $k$ if this is neccesary.

Comment: If you want your condition to hold for all $n$, only $f(k)=0$ will satisfy your inequality (for every $n$ up to $k^2$, $S_n$ is smaller than $k\sqrt{n}$ almost surely). You may want your inequality to hold for $n$ large enough. Then the central limit theorem provides you a solution as stated earlier in the comments.

Comment: @tristan - edited. We can view $k$ as fixed.